# Getting Transparent-Background PNGs from an SWF Animation?

Tags: flash

I have an artist I'm paying to do animation art for me. I need PNGs for each frame in the animation but she is most comfortable doing her animations in Flash. It sounds like getting the frames for me will be difficult for her. Does anyone know of an easy way to do this? Also keeping in mind that if it's something that needs to be done on her end we can recommend it, we just don't know anything about Flash.

She was able to do the still art we needed and give us that as a frame, but for some reason the animation is different?

Keep in mind we need PNGs with full transparency support in the background. We can't be clipping these frames out by hand.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can export a frame as PNG. Just go to

```
File > Export > Export Image > PNG
```

Then choose `24 bit with alpha channel` in the colors drop down to allow transparency.

**Edit 2:** Alas, there is even a better way! Once the movie is created, she can go to

```
File > Export Movie...
```

And choose PNG Sequence from the drop down menu, same color settings apply, and it will batch create all the PNG files you need.

Comment: So she would just do that for each frame? Sounds simple enough. Perhaps she's worried about the sheer number of frames?

Comment: Cool, thanks! Do you know if there is any free software out there that we can use to create these frames for her if she gives us her source files? If this is too much work for her we'd be content just to let her focus on creation and we can do the utilitarian work.

Comment: Nah I don't think so, but you can download a free trial from adobe.com. Did you see the latest edit about the batch export? With one command you can export every frame as a separate PNG.

Answer (score -1):

as far as i can see flash or Animate do not export transparent png sequnce, and exporting 120 frames (for example) one by one is not fun at all

Comment: Please provide a link to the relevant documentation.